# AutoPostBack not working for custom control

Tags: asp.net, custom-controls, autopostback

I have created a custom control in ASP.net which includes a DropDownList with AutoPostBack set to true. I have also attached an event SelectedIndexChanged for the control.But I find that the event is not fired. Where as normal asp.net DropDownList with AutoPostBack set to true will fire the event. I am using .net 3.5 version in VS2010.

Here is my code:
**ServerControl1.cs**

```
[ToolboxData("<{0}:ServerControl2 runat=server></{0}:ServerControl2>")]
public class ServerControl1 : WebControl
{
    protected DropDownList drplist;
    protected TextBox tb;

    protected override void RenderContents(HtmlTextWriter output)
    {
        drplist.RenderControl(output);
        tb.RenderControl(output);

    }

    protected override void CreateChildControls()
    {
        base.CreateChildControls();
        drplist = new DropDownList() { AutoPostBack = true };
        drplist.Items.Add("a");
        drplist.Items.Add("b");
        drplist.Items.Add("c");
        drplist.Items.Add("d");
        drplist.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(drplist_SelectedIndexChanged);
        tb = new TextBox();
    }

    void drplist_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      tb.Text = "even fired";          
    }
}
```

**ServerControl1Test:**

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ServerControl1 ServerControl1 = new ServerControl1();
        this.Controls.Add(ServerControl1);
    }
```

Can anyone tell me what am I missing here?

Answer (score 2):

First, you need your custom controls to be a part of the page tree. In this case ASP.NET will be able to find them and include all required scripts (if any). You don't need to override `RenderContents`. Simply add your drop-down list as well as the textbox to the `Controls` collection.

Second, please read the [API reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.createchildcontrols.aspx) for `CreateChildControls`. There is comment at the bottom of the page that states:

> Do not override `CreateChildControls`!
>
> You will run into a world of hurt,
>   **especially when it comes to subscribing to child control events**!
>   Instead, create a private method
>   called, `CreateCustomChildControls`.
>   Build your control tree there. Simply
>   override `OnInit` and call
>   `CreateCustomChildControls` from
>   there.

So in your case the code will look like the following:

```
[ToolboxData("<{0}:ServerControl2 runat=server></{0}:ServerControl2>")]
public class ServerControl1 : WebControl
{
    protected DropDownList drplist;
    protected TextBox tb;

    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnInit(e);

        CreateCustomChildControls();
    }

    private void CreateCustomChildControls()
    {
            drplist = new DropDownList() { AutoPostBack = true };

            drplist.Items.Add("a");
            drplist.Items.Add("b");
            drplist.Items.Add("c");
            drplist.Items.Add("d");

            drplist.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(drplist_SelectedIndexChanged);

            tb = new TextBox();

            base.Controls.Add(drplist);
            base.Controls.Add(tb);
    }

    void drplist_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tb.Text = "even fired";
    }
}
```